# eslint unable to find built-in flow types

Tags: eslint, flowtype

```
error  'SyntheticUIEvent' is not defined  no-undef
```

for:

```
handleDocumentKeyUp = (event: SyntheticUIEvent) => {}
```

I'm getting this for one of the open source projects I'm working on ([eslintrc.js](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/next/.eslintrc.js)) but not in my own app code, but I can't spot the difference or error in linting setup.

What configuration is missing/wrong that would be make eslint unable to find build-in flow types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable the [flowtype/define-flow-type](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype#define-flow-type) rule in your config, it should tell ESLint about the Flow types.

Comment: Woohoo! I missed that one.